# Discord music bot error reading '_attempts'

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have made a Discord music bot and have made it connect successfully, but it can't handle the playing audio part.

`yt-search`, `ytdl-core` and `discord.js` are the latest versions.

This is my **play.js** command

```
const ytsearch = require('yt-search');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const fs = require('fs');
const {
    createAudioPlayer,
    createAudioResource,
    AudioPlayer,
    VoiceConnection,
    joinVoiceChannel
  } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const player = createAudioPlayer();

const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'],
    cooldown: 0,
    description: 'play the song damn it',
    
    async execute(message,args,command,client,Discord) {
        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;

        if(!voice_channel) {
            return message.channel.send('get in a voice channel first')
        } else {
            joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        })}

        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message,client.user);
        if(!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('you dont have the correct permissions');
        if(!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('you dont have the correct permissions');
        
        if (command === 'play'){
            if(!args.length) {
                return message.channel.send('play what?')
            }else {
                console.log(args)

                const stream = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
                
                const resource = createAudioResource(stream);
        
                async function play() {
                    await player.play(resource);
                    connection.subscribe(player);
            
                }
                const videoFinder = async (query) => {
                    const videoResult = await ytsearch(query);
                    return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
                }
                console.log('The args 0 is ')
                console.log(args[0])
                const video = await videoFinder(args[1]);

                if (video){
                    play(video);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

When I send the message with the link it outputs this error and I can't figure it out

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_attempts')
at search (C:\Users\mi_ke\Desktop\SpoonBot\node_modules\yt-search\dist\yt-search.js:133:34)
at _options.query (C:\Users\mi_ke\Desktop\SpoonBot\node_modules\yt-search\dist\yt-search.js:115:7)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at search (C:\Users\mi_ke\Desktop\SpoonBot\node_modules\yt-search\dist\yt-search.js:114:12)
at module.exports (C:\Users\mi_ke\Desktop\SpoonBot\node_modules\yt-search\dist\yt-search.js:94:10)
at videoFinder (C:\Users\mi_ke\Desktop\SpoonBot\commands\play.js:56:47)
at Object.execute (C:\Users\mi_ke\Desktop\SpoonBot\commands\play.js:61:37)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mi_ke\Desktop\SpoonBot\main.js:42:37)
at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\mi_ke\Desktop\SpoonBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:34:18)
```

`yt-search` is the latest version. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `args[1]` is not `undefined` in `videoFinder(args[1])`?

Comment: Oh I can't believe this. I changed it to make sure I wasn't using the wrong one and forgot to change it back.